# Xcode error message not making logical sense

Tags: c, xcode

I'm supposed to be generating a program that creates a thread that generates a random number between 0 and 1 and prints out the generated random number.

The error messages I'm receiving from Xcode don't make any logical sense. I tried many different methods, I might just be overlooking it but I could don't see any possible syntax errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printMsg(char* msg) {
    int status = 0;
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    pthread_exit(&status);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t thrdID;
    int* status = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("creating a new thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thrdID, NULL, (void*)printMsg, argv[1]);
    printf("created thread %d\n". thrdID);
    pthread_join(thrdID, &status);
    printf("Thread %d exited with status %d\n", thrdID, *status);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing? You don't mention any!

Comment: You have a period `.` in the second `printf` in `main`.

Comment: I see your example, but I was generating a program that creates a thread that generates a random number between 0 and 1 and prints out the generated random number.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see it now, you had a period instead of a comma here:

```
    printf("created thread %d\n". thrdID);
```

should be

```
    printf("created thread %d\n", thrdID);
```

It was pointed out in some now deleted comments, that there were other issues with the code that should be corrected.

These are some suggestions about how to deal with these issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printMsg(char* msg) {
    // The stack of the thread will be destryed on exit
    // so you need to allocate the status value (or do some
    // rather dubious casting... this is cleaner).
    int* status_pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    // For demonstration purposes set it to something other than 0.
    *status_pointer = 123;
    pthread_exit(status_pointer);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t thrdID;
    void* status = NULL;
    printf("creating a new thread\n");
    // You should not blindly pass argv[1] without checking it's valid.
    // You can provide a default value like I did below, or error out.
    char *msg = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "This is a default message.";
    pthread_create(&thrdID, NULL, (void*)printMsg, msg);
    // thrdId is pointer so use the %p format specifier.
    printf("created thread %p\n", thrdID);
    pthread_join(thrdID, &status);
    // same issue with %p
    printf("Thread %p exited with status %d\n", thrdID, *(int*)status);
    // don't forget to free what you allocated.
    free(status);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see your example, but I was generating a program that creates a thread that generates a random number between 0 and 1 and prints out the generated random number.

Comment: Well that's not the program you posted... How are we meant to know about program code that you do not include in your question?

Comment: To be clear, the code in my answer is the code you posted with all the errors and warnings fixed.